# Python get Request inside Flask context fails with 504 Gateway Error

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, consul

> I want to make an interface for a user in order to request a REST API of a KV base
>
> For this need I used flask, requests and Python (tested with 2.7 & 3.6)
>
> requests : 2.18.4  ,   Flask  : 0.12.2

My API accessible for user is written like that :

Purpose is client can access /getval and retrieve a value in the KV

```
# for testing
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello From PYTHON"

@app.route("/getval")
def getval():
    val0 = getKVval(url)
    return val0
```

my get call to retrieve the value from my KV product is defined here

```
def getKVval(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    # If Key does not exist set to defaultVal
    if r.status_code == 404:
        setConsulVal(url, defaultval)
        return defaultval
    o = json.loads(r.content)
    valb64 = o[0]['Value']
    dec = base64.b64decode(valb64)
    return dec
```

When I start my python process everything is OK

```
Restarting with stat
Debugger is active!
Debugger PIN: 241-055-893
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

Process is UP and can be accessed by Client on default port (5000)

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:5000
Hello From PYTHON App
```

> the issue start when try to access /getval

When I call my function getKVval without flask it works perfectly

```
StatusCode : 200
[{u'LockIndex': 0, u'ModifyIndex': 34, u'Value': u'Mw==', u'Flags': 0, u'Key': u'mysqld/serverid', u'CreateIndex': 31}]
Mw==
3
```

However when I try to access with /getval it crashes an error

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2018 10:44:53] "GET /getval HTTP/1.1" 500 -
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "...venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "...venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "...venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "...venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
File "...venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "...venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "...venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "...venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
File "...venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "...venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "...interface\interface.py", line 82, in getval
    val0 = getConsulVal(url)
File "...interface\interface.py", line 36, in getConsulVal
    o = json.loads(r.content)
File "....Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "....Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "....Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I have done many debugs (with / without proxy configuration) , printing output ... but can't find anything right now

**EDIT & SOLUTION:**

just found some more logs in my app that returns before the error :

> ('Status Code: ', 504)
>
> HTTP 504 IS 'GATEWAY TIMEOUT' Error

So I did some more testing to desactivate / configure Proxy

I try this configuration that did not solve :

```
proxies = {
    "http": None,
    "https": None,
}
```

then calls it with

```
r = requests.get(url, proxies)
```

Result : no success with it ...

**FINAL SOLUTION :**

```
os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = '127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: You need to return a JSON

Comment: Is that works with  `requests.get(url).json()`

Comment: You can do `from flask import jsonify`, and in your `getval` function, do `return jsonify(val0)`.